# Set a input value HTML and submit, using console

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I have a problem, on my work i need create a code for send barcodes in webaapp, submit and get response, but i don't have permission install softwares in computers, I can only access the webapp within the company's computers due to a network limitation. Is there any way for me to do all this using just the Google Chrome devtools console, and generate a json with the data I collect?

My initial idea was to use Python and Selenium, but that won't be possible...